# making bootstrap navbar disappear and reappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out how to make the navbar in bootstrap disappear when scrolling down past the first portion of the page and reappear at a certain point. Any help is appreciated!

html:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Waymond</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">attending organizations</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#about">shop</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">blog</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">womp</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">friends</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact" class="cta">help</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

Here is my failing js:

```
$(window).scroll(
{
    previousTop: 0
},
function () {
   var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
   if (currentTop < this.previousTop) {
       $(".navbar").hide();
   } else {
       $(".navbar").show();
    }
    this.previousTop = currentTop;
});
```

Comment: Think you can create a simple fiddle for this?

Comment: It may be easier for you to use Bootstrap affix: http://www.bootply.com/CP89OmIef5

Comment: @Adjit Sure. Only problem is I don't know which css to copy and there is a lot (first time using bootstrap).

Comment: I made a JSFiddle, but I think Baghoo already cracked it! http://jsfiddle.net/c6QFD/

Comment: @Waymond yeah, I think Baghoo took care of the issue. Don't worry about the fiddle.

Comment: @Baghoo Thank you!!! That worked. Thanks to everyone else too.